# 2Gb free but can’t record video

Tags: iphone, icloud, storage

My phone says it has paused uploading images to iCloud, despite there being 25Gb space free there, and it won’t record video due to lack of storage on the device, despite it having over 2Gb free.

What’s wrong with it?

Comment: Does plugging it into power and locking the screen while connected to wifi start the upload? 2GB is pretty close to "lack of storage" imo, I'm not too sure about this but maybe iOS prevents the camera from using up all free space.

Comment: Signed out iCloud for now.

Comment: I think low power mode pauses uploads.